# CQRS - Quando usar e porque usar?

Tags: c#, .net, design-pattern

Quais são as vantagens de usar o padrão CQRS (Command/Query Responsibility Segregation) ? Quais seriam as desvantagens ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em resumo, o CQRS é útil e recomendado em cenários de domínios complexos ou em aplicações de alta performance.

Parfraseando a documentação da Microsoft, quando comparado ao modelo de CRUD convencional:

> Comparado com o modelo de dados único utilizado em sistemas baseados
>   em CRUD, o uso de modelos de atualização e consulta separados para os
>   dados em sistemas baseados em CQRS simplifica o design e a
>   implementação. No entanto, uma desvantagem é que, ao contrário de
>   projetos CRUD, o código CQRS não pode ser gerado automaticamente
>   utilizando mecanismos de scaffold.

Então uma das maiores vantagens é a melhora de desempenho em aplicações complexas e uma das maiores desvantagens é o possível aumento de complexidade do código que representa o modelo. Porém, o CQRS não é recomendado em todos os cenários.

Cenários recomendados:

- Domínios colaborativos com operações paralelas no mesmo modelo de dados.
- Interfaces de usuário baseada em tarefas divididas em várias etapas
- Sistemas onde a quantidade de leitura de dados é muito maior que o número de gravação
- Cenários onde a regra de negócio é alterada com frequência
- Integraçõe entre sistemas, onde a falha de um não pode parar o outro

Cenários não recomendados:

- Domínios com regras de negócio simples (por exemplo aplicações baseadas em CRUD)

Além disso, de acordo com recomendações do Martin Fowler, o padrão CQRS deve ser aplicado em partes de um sistema e não nele como um todo. Tentar implementar esse padrão em um sistema cuja complexidade não é compatível só vai diminuir consideravelmente a produtividade e complexidade do desenvolvimento. Considere também a experiência da equipe com o DDD, pois uma equipe imatura quanto a implementação correta de domínios ricos pode ser desastrosa na tentativa de implementar o CQRS.

Não há nenhuma diferença entre implementar esse padrão com .NET Core ou outro framework ou linguagem, as considerações em usar (ou não) não se limitam a uma questão técnica.

Fontes:

Documentação da Microsoft:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs

Martin Fowler:
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta. Ajudou bastante :D